# JFrog CLI - Fail to use CLI for build-docker-create (bdc) command

Tags: artifactory

Trying to use ***jf rt bdc*** (***build-docker-create***) command, with no success. Whatever value I set to *--image-file* command option, I get an error message: "no such file or directory" although digest is provided together with tag for the image. Any detailed example of a full command that runs fine? thanks

I've tried to use:
*jf rt bdc  <internal path of image within the repo with @* - same for trying with partial image path - all tries provided an error message "no such file or directory". Set the log level to DEBUG did not provided any more information.

Answer (score 0):

The `--image-file` is path to a local file in the running machine, includes one line in the following format: `<IMAGE-TAG>@sha256:<MANIFEST-SHA256>`.

This file is automatically generated by Kaniko or Buildx, for example:

```
# Build the Docker image and create the build-metadata file:
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 --tag=DOCKER_REG_URL/TARGET_REPO/multiarch-image:1 -f=Dockerfile.Fatmanifest --metadata-file=build-metadata --push .

# Run build-docker-create:
jf rt build-docker-create TARGET_REPO --server-id=MY_SERVER_ID --image-file build-metadata --build-name myBuild --build-number 1
```

Full examples:

- [Fat Manifest](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/docker-oci-examples/fat-manifest-example)
- [Kaniko](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/docker-oci-examples/kaniko-example)

Documentation:

- [Adding Published Docker Images to the Build-Info](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/adding-published-docker-images-to-the-build-info)

Comment: thanks @yahavi!  Your reply helped to get the results, but requiredcorrections:

1.  **--image-file** should be used with **=**. E.g. **--image-file=<file path>**

2. The build-metadata file generated by buildx is a json file with 2 keys:

`{
  "containerimage.config.digest": "sha256:a1ad1f9950574245969354f966d83beb813c83cb50a50a4c240ff136ebc13ed2",
  "containerimage.digest": "sha256:ed189d5a7f81b39a5d5d832b38339e13efcf242d6d47b2f955cfa5541b236d9d"
}`


I needed to convert to a single line format with the image digest only.

Comment: @NiraShavitt, you dont have to use '=', it is kind of style. Both should work.
As for the generated file by buildx, JFrog-cli knows how to parse buildx generated file. Could you try to run this example?:
https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/docker-oci-examples/fat-manifest-example
 it uses buildx with JFrog-cli.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example: https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/docker-oci-examples/fat-manifest-example the

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 --tag=DOCKER_REG_URL/TARGET_REPO/multiarch-image:1 -f=Dockerfile.Fatmanifest --metadata-file=build-metadata --push .` generated "build-metadata"
```

is NOT compatible with the format needed by the jfrog CLI command's

```
jf rt build-docker-create TARGET_REPO --server-id=MY_SERVER_ID --image-file build-metadata --build-name myBuild --build-number 1
```

command.

Working with jFrog support, they suggested generating a new build-metadata file using the generated one's contents, that combines some of the data in the original build-metadata into a single line. eg:

```
    jfrog_image_name="$(printf "%s@%s" $(jq -r '.["image.name", "containerimage.digest"]' < build-metadata))"
    echo "${jfrog_image_name}" > build-metadata
```

The above creates a file containing only the "@sha256:" format mentioned in the

```
jf rt build-docker-create -h
```

output.

IOW: from the original build-metadata file:

```
<IMAGE-TAG> = image.name
sha256:<MANIFEST-SHA256> = containerimage.digest
```

No idea why this is not mentioned in the fat-manifest example.
Did something change with file formats and the docs never got updated?

The last thing to note is that the `<target repo>` in the `jf rt build-docker-create  <target repo>` command is the "name", not "URL".